# writing the output of m.start() - m.end() into a list

Tags: regex, python-3.x, list

I have a string that I want to remove gaps from. I have found the beginning and the end position of the gaps, but I don't want to print to the screen.

Instead, I want to save it as a list.

Here's the code I have:

```
S1= "AAAA--TTT--GCCTT--GGG"    
import re
    t=[]
    p = re.compile("-+")
    for m in p.finditer(s1):
        t.append(m.end()-m.start()) ## This produces an error. I want to save the output as a list
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
 S1= "AAAA--TTT--GCCTT--GGG"
 S2 = S1.replace('--', ' ')
 l = list(S2.split(' '))
```

Gets you this output `['AAAA', 'TTT', 'GCCTT', 'GGG']`

Comment: Thank you but this is not exactly what I want. My intention is to get a list containing the following t=[2,2,2]

Comment: But what do these `[2,2,2]` refer to?

Comment: it is print(m.end()-m.start())

Answer (score 0):

this is output of `print(m.end()-m.start())`

```
2
2
2
```

so I want the output saved as a list `t= [2,2,2]` instead of printing to the screen